# Nyan/TAP/List Reporter for Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, tap

I am using `mocha` and `chai` for testing my `NodeJS` application. But I am not able to figure out how to use reporting tools like `Nyan` or others. I could not find any tutorial for this also. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `$ mocha --help | grep reporter`

Answer (score 0):

with mocha nyan:

```
mocha test.js -R nyan
```